# how to assign hostname for rabbitmq cluster on Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, rabbitmq

Dears,
I am trying to setup Rabbitmq cluster on Azure Kubernetes Service.

I am using the example yaml files provided here:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/tree/master/examples/k8s_statefulsets

I got this error and pod keep restarting:

```
Failed to get nodes from k8s - {failed_connect,[{to_address,{"kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",443}},
                 {inet,[inet],nxdomain}]}
```

I know the meaning of the error. but, what grinds my gears is I don't know how to assign a hostname for the cluster. or from where I got the right one!

I've searched the entire Internet, I can find any useful answer for this question.
all answers from kind "you need to specify your host name" ... OK i really need to do that .. but how?

this line from the rabbitmq configurations:

```
cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

and it's a default value.
I don't what is the right value? do I need to create something? to get specific hostname from somewhere?

Comment: its the default value and its there by default in AKS cluster

Comment: yeah .. I need to change it .. but change it to what?

Comment: if you mean it's already there in the cluster so why I got "not exist domain" error !!

Comment: means dns in the cluster is not working, can you test that it works?

Comment: I don't know how to test it .. but I have "kube-dns" service running on "kube-system" namespace .. if this what you mean?

Comment: according to the docs that value is correct, can you do `kubectl get svc -n default` and see if the service called `kubernetes` exists?

Comment: yes, exists and port 443 is open. the type of it is ClusterIP

Comment: is your cluster rbac enabled? it needs to be rbac enabled for this to work

Comment: You can set the cluster name through Serverip:15672.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys,

after working with two of my colleagues in this issue.
we've solved the issue by recreating the AKS with defined `--service-cidr` and `--dns-service-ip`

because if you left them blank, Azure will create unrealistic values for them. even when you select a specific subnet!!

moreover, the `--dns-service-ip` must be the 10th ip of the defined range!!

```
az aks create `
--location region `
--resource-group rgname `
--vnet-subnet-id ***** `
--name clustername `
--node-count 2 `
--service-principal ****
--client-secret ****
--network-plugin azure `
--docker-bridge-address 172.17.0.1/16 `
--service-cidr 10.1.1.0/24 `
--dns-service-ip 10.1.1.10 `
--generate-ssh-keys
```